# Unable to debug classic asp code in Visual Studio 2013/2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, vbscript, asp-classic

I've tried all possible ways but not able to debug the classic code. I tried attaching the process to IIS and enabled debug in IIS, tried several steps but still no luck, any help will be very much appreciated.

I've tried all the related articles still no luck so im posting this for more help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.Open Visual Studio 2010

2.Open your website in Visual Studio

3.Fire up your web site.

4.In Visual Studio, click ‘Debug’ Menu -> ‘Attach to process’

5.You may need to tick the box labelled ‘Show processes from all users’

6.‘Inetinfo.exe‘ if application protection is low or ”dllhost.exe‘ if application protection is higher. You may get an ‘Attach Security Warning’ popup. If so, continue On. It’s a bit scary at first, but if it’s your own app on your own PC, then you’ll be ok.

7.Add a breakpoint to your code, and navigate to a location where you will hit it.

Source: http://www.jameswiseman.com/blog/2010/10/12/debugging-classic-asp-from-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Thank you very very much:) Problem solved

Comment: I Followed steps 1 to 5 and that did the magic...

Comment: @JP you mean the same steps here - [How do you debug classic ASP?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1138210)?

Comment: The steps mentioned above by John!